# Fresh Homestead not working on Windows (composer rename permission denied error)

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm running a fresh version of Homestead v8.0.1 on windows.

My Homestead.yml file looks something like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.99.20"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

backup: true

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/example
      to: /home/vagrant/code/dealer-app

sites:
    - map: example.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/example/public
      type: "apache"

databases:
    - example

ports:
    - send: 4200
      to: 4200
    - send: 49153
      to: 49153
```

I did the following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git .
$ git checkout v8.0.1
$ init.bat
$ vagrant up
```

Most of it works until I get this error:

```
homestead-7: Running: script: Update Composer
homestead-7: Updating to version 1.8.2 (stable channel).
homestead-7:
homestead-7:
homestead-7:   [ErrorException]
homestead-7:   rename(/home/vagrant/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied
```

Why is this not working?

Looking at `homestead.rb` it has:

```
 config.vm.provision 'shell' do |s|
      s.name = 'Update Composer'
      s.inline = 'sudo -u vagrant /usr/local/bin/composer self-update --no-progress && sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.composer/'
      s.privileged = false
  end
```

So it could be an issue with chown running on Windows version of Vagrant perhaps?

**UPDATE**

I managed to solved this issue by editing `homestead.rb` composer portion to:

```
config.vm.provision 'shell' do |s|
  s.name = 'Update Composer'
  s.inline = '/usr/local/bin/composer self-update --no-progress && chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.composer/'
  s.privileged = true
  # s.inline = 'sudo -u vagrant /usr/local/bin/composer self-update --no-progress && sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.composer/'
  # s.privileged = false
end
```

Is this correct? Is this a Homestead bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Homestead [bug](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/commit/d417d4f9fbb04ad72790bb748981ee498082ef2a) which was fixed in v8.0.2.

[Updating](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#updating-homestead) to the latest version should fix it.

NB: Make sure you run `git checkout v8.0.2`, and not `git checkout v8.0.1` as the docs say right now.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a usual setup procedure.

I suggest to follow the guide [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#first-steps).

After you've run init.bat, you should then set up your homestead.yaml file, only then running vagrant up.

Comment: That's what I did. The Homestead.yml file isn't the problem. I updated the question anyhow.